# delete records from store with checkbox selection

Tags: php, sql, extjs

I have this ajax request that iterates through a store and deletes all selected records.

code

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'system/index.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        class: 'LicenseFeatures',
        method: 'delete',
        data: Ext.encode({
        feature_id: ( function(){
                var e = "";
                var sel = Ext.getCmp('featureGrid').getSelection();
                var c = 0;
                for( var i in sel ) {
                    var x = ( c == 0 ) ?  e = sel[i].data.feature_id : e += "," + sel[i].data.feature_id;
                    c++;
                }
                return e;
            })()
    })

},
                 success: function( response ){
    Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Status', 'Record(s) has been deleted.' );
    Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore').reload();
},
    failure: function(){
        Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Status', 'Failed to delete records.' );
    }
});
```

Currently the code retrieves 1 id from the grid and deletes it. What I need to do is get two Id's from the grid as I need to run a specific sql to the database. The sql needs two inputs, here is the sql

```
public function delete( $vars ){
$sql = "DELETE FROM `LicenseFeatures` WHERE feature_id in({$vars->data->feature_id}) AND license_id in({$vars->data->license_id})";
if( $result = $vars->db->query( $sql ) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( "success" => true,"sql"=>$sql ) );
} else {
    echo json_encode( array( "success" => false ) );
}
}
```

Comment: If I havent explained clearly please say so

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Are you talking about the license_id attribute  that you use in the sql query?

Comment: yes exactly, I need to submit that attribute along with the feature_id attribute

Comment: sorry that javascript may be confusing to you

Comment: So you want to add the feature_id property to the ajax request. What's the problem?

Comment: No feature_id is already there as you see in the javascript, however I need to add license_id with it

Comment: Oh. Yea that's what I meant. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: yes so I need to add license_id into the javascript for statement

Comment: basically will enable be to delete both attributes in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change the data property to this.

```
data: Ext.encode(( function(){
    var feature_id,
        licence_id;
    var sel = Ext.getCmp('featureGrid').getSelection();
    var c = 0;
    for( var i in sel ) {
        if (c == 0) {
            feature_id = sel[i].data.feature_id;
            licence_id = sel[i].data.licence_id;
        } else {
            feature_id += "," + sel[i].data.feature_id;
            licence_id += "," + sel[i].data.licence_id;
        }
        c++;
    }
    return {
        feature_id: feature_id,
        licence_id: licence_id
    };
})())
```

Comment: Its working, but not deleting specific records it seems to be deleting all records with those features, complicated to explain but I will work through it

Comment: That's exactly what you're telling it to do. If you only want to delete two records you will have to find a column that is unique to those records.